# Ember View - Recursive view call throws Stop Script Error

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have to construct a tree structure like the below image.

[image]

For this I use a Ember View and recursively call to construct the whole tree like structure based on the supplied model.

My Templates are:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="zd-fldr fleft" style="width:230px;">   
        <ul class="fldr-sub">
            {{#each item in model}}
                {{view App.FoldertreeView model=item contentBinding="item"}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foldertree">
    {{#if item.subfolder }}
        <span {{action 'getSubFolder' item}} {{bind-attr class="item.IS_OPENED:fdtree-icon:ftree-icon"}}> </span>
    {{else}}    
        <span class=""> </span>
    {{/if}}
    <span style="padding-top:20px;" class="fdetail fleft" >{{item.FOLDER_NAME}}</span>

    <ul style="margin-top:30px;" {{bind-attr class="item.IS_OPENED:showdiv:hidediv"}}>
        {{#each item in item.children}}
            {{view "foldertree" model=item contentBinding="item"}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul> 
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var treeArray = [];

        for(var i=0; i<4000; i++){
            var temp_obj = { 'FETCHED_DATA': false, 'FOLDER_ID': i, 'FOLDER_NAME': 'Folder_'+i, 'IS_OPENED': false, 'opened': true, 'subfolder': true, 'children': [] };
            treeArray.push(temp_obj);
        }
        return treeArray;
   } 
});

App.FoldertreeView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    templateName: 'foldertree',
    classNames: ['treediv', 's-fldr']
});
```

Initially I load only the first level folders from the server by calling an API.

Then when the open node is clicked, the children array is filled by calling an request to the server.

Now when the model length is greater than 3000 "Stop Script" error is thrown in Firefox browser.

In my tree there is no limit for the number of nodes. How can I solve this problem.

Demo [JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qiqege/2/) (Try it in Firefox)

Comment: Don't you think that the for loop cycle is too big. I suggest you to keep it small. You can add or push more objects later according to your need.

Comment: I have had a nearly identical problem, although I was using partials instead of views. Still tracking it down. My suspicion is that it's a bug in Ember/HBS.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You mention "recursively", but the code you posted seems to be just doing a single level of 4000 elements, so the `{{#each item in item.children}}` loop will never be executed AFAICT. You're not testing Ember's ability to handle recursive views, but rather to handle many many views. I myself have tested Ember with a models with 10000 elements, each of which was displayed using a view, and it ran out of gas very quickly. The overhead in constructing views is huge. You might want to try using partials instead.

Comment: @torazaburo If there is child objects it will be added in the children array which will run recursively. So that I can have a tree like structure as like the image attached. Now for rendering the first level model itself(without child objects) I got Stop Script error.

Comment: You got the stop script error because of the huge number of views. If I understand what you are trying to do correctly you should do a test with three objects each with three children and so on recursively some number of levels. That will separate out two issues: (1) do the recursive views work properly, and (2) how many views can Ember handle, independent of whether flat or nested.

Answer (score 1):

Ember is a web framework.  Given that information, you need to realize that you can't efficiently render 6000 items in a browser without reusing some view elements.  Even native applications don't do this: in iOS, for instance, the cells in a TableView are reusable, so a table displaying a collection of 6000 items only has enough cells to cover the height of he view and some scrolling overlap.  The view is aware of its scroll location, and renders the 10-20 items that need to be rendered from the collection, and when you scroll down it removes the top element, places an element at the bottom, and renders the next item in the data array.  This way, everyone wins.  I would suggest you do the same, as JS/HTML just can't handle that many elements efficiently.

I know it's not a fun implementation, but once you come up with a component that does this the first time, you'll be glad you did.

Honorable mentions: https://github.com/emberjs/list-view.  You're doing a file tree and not a list, which is more difficult than just a long list, but you may still be able to use it if you change up your UI a little bit.  If you have the folder structure navigable with a tree and show files in a list-view, this may mitigate your issue depending on whether the problem is with a number of files or a number of folders.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I need to render long tree structures which contains only folders and sub folders. I will try lazy loading for tree rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an Ember issue but a general javascript issue. When a script is taking to long time to execute this kind of errors message are displayed / fired by the browser and it's different on each browser.

You can read [this good blog post about long time runing scripts](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/05/what-determines-that-a-script-is-long-running/)

If you have browser environment undercontroll (i mean your computer our your companies computers) you can still [setup firefox to run longer scripts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/warning-unresponsive-script#w_letting-the-script-run-longer)

However a good practice would be to "split" your script in sub task taking less time to execute.

**EDIT**

Ass discussed in the comments this is due to the Huge number of view you generate. You can have 6000 models returned from your backend however generating 6000 view at once is heavy.

Here is a proposition on how to handle this : http://jsbin.com/zakisoyesi/6/edit?html,js,output free to you to adapt it to your use case and event to make it transparent to the user by using onScroll or any other event.

Comment: I disagree with this analysis. I think it's a bug in Ember/HBS.

Comment: @torazaburo did you actually open the script in firefox and or chrome and saw howmany times it's take to run ? i did it, and obviously the script takes to much time to execute that's the ground problem...

Comment: @MrVinz This is not generic issue. In my demo I have used general for loop to construct the object and returned in model. The Ember View renders the model recursively and the Script Error is thrown.

Comment: @Jeevi a recursive function or a for loop are both "blocking" the execution, but obviously it's not 6000 object push in a loop that takes long time and kills the script it's the fact that ember does some magic behind and if you provide your 6000 object at once it's take time to render.

Comment: @MrVinz If you check in the jsbin link I have calculated the time take by the for loop. Its around 8 to 10 ms only. http://jsbin.com/qiqege/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Jeevi it's exactly what i'm saying ;) in my previous comment. However you have to consider that in your template you then render 6000 views which instantiate 6000 views objects and so on... it's not magic, i'm working on your jsbin i come back later to you :)

Comment: @Jeevi i've made you a jsbin with an alternative let you adapt it :)

Comment: @MrVinz Thanks for your reply, I have checked the changes but I cant go with the scrolling implementation. At times I need to load the whole tree from the server. If the user has bookmarked the url for a folder in 4000th position then when he access the folder I need to load the whole tree as such and select the particular folder.

Comment: @Jeevi well my implemention is an example of how to handle this situation you have to adapt it and yes it s a bit of work... if someone bookmarke a foolder it means you work with anckors or other params thus you can adjust the data to display/load. You can also play with Ember.run [to replace setTimeout] to load progressively the display array. This is a base reciep to solve your problem now your job to adapt it :)

Comment: @MrVinz It's a JS and "rendering way too much to the DOM" issue.  You can't blame Ember for your poor design choices.

Comment: @mpowered, just to be clear it's not my design choice, i told the author that it was not a good thing to load 6k views :). After, if we had to identify what slows up the whole process, for sure the DOM manipulations which result from the view rendering process are for sure one of the bottle neck.

Comment: Not sure what to say here... It doesn't matter whose decision is was, it's not going to work that way.